# Have a issue with the structured data of my website

Tags: wordpress, schema, google-rich-snippets, structured-data, yoast

My website is on WordPress and has a Yoast plugin for SEO.

Problem:- My website it changed but Google but in result it shows the older pages that I had on my older website as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAmsW.png) and I want to display my new pages.

I have indexed it in the search console and other tools as well. I have not put any structured data manually for this otherwise I would have changed it, I am not able to find the solution on how to solve this.